# Car idles fine, but gas pedal doesn't do anything after failed jump start

Tags: toyota, camry, jump-start, pedals

I have a 2006 Toyota Camry LE. Just the other day my car battery died so I asked my neighbor for a jump. My husband normally would handle it but I took it into my hands that day being that the lady said she knew what she was doing. Long story short cables get hooked up and 2 mins later I see my jumper cables smoking and melting! Quickly she unhooked the cables and a guy comes by and jumps the car using something else. The car starts running just fine but I didn't try to drive anywhere at that moment ... a couple hours later my husband goes out and he saw the fuse cover on the inside was missing, but we don't see anything gone or cut ... so he starts the car and the gas pedal won't even let us drive! And it was just working the night before ... My questions are:

- Did someone do something to the fuse on the inside?
- Or is there anyway I can drive again?
- What's happened to my pedals?
- Did my neighbors careless mistake brrsk my car?

Please help me and my husband are totally clueless

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! First place to start is to check all the fuses and see which ones might have been blown. With the jumpers on there backwards, terrible things can happen. Hopefully the fuses took the brunt of it. There will most likely be two fuse boxes, one inside the car and one under the hood. Check **ALL** of the fuses inside. If you have a multi-meter, check to see the battery is getting charged while running (~14.1-14.6vdc).